# Getting error when trying to delete item in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

ErrorException (E_NOTICE) Trying to get property of non-object. Old items deleted succesfully this issue occurs in new added items.

```
public function getItemPreviewToDelete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('pre_item_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('zd_item_previews');
        return $query->row(2)->pre_name;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you always have a value in $query->row(2)->pre_name? why row(2)?

Comment: Do a var_dump of $query and look what's inside it (and what $query->row really is, if it exists at all)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you are getting *pre_name* or not by adding below code

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($query->result_array());
print "</pre>";
```

Before this line

```
return $query->row(2)->pre_name;
```